# unordered list collapses when user shrinks window

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists

I have a simple set of tabular data in an unordered list.  I need the table to stay fixed width and have scroll bars appear if the users browser is too small or if they shrink their browser.  Instead, the unordered list is collapsing into itself:

http://www.actionmediadesign.com/unordered_list_table.html

I need that unordered list to stay fixed width, regardless of the window size around it.  Thanks in advance for any help with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Give your `ul` a fixed width:

```
#sortable_list{width:1560px;}
```

Update:

If you want the scrollbars to only appear inside your 'table' you should try wrapping your `ul` into a `div` with `overflow-x:auto`:

HTML:

```
<div id="table-wrapper">
    <ul id="sortable_list">
        [ Your li's here.. ]
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#table-wrapper{overflow-x:auto;}
#sortable_list{width:1560px;}
```

Comment: beat me to it. same answer for me.

Comment: @JPT145 I've updated my answer but I see you removed the question that you put in the comments, so I guess it works now?

Answer (score 0):

You should give it a fixed width but since you want it scrollable wrap t inside a div and give that div an `overflow-y: auto;` and then your whole page will not have a horizontal scroll and it will only be contained to the table.